# How to inject js files into a html page when loading?

Tags: javascript

I'm a tester and I'm going to test a page `index.htm`. I'm not allowed to change the target.

To test the page, I need to change some production code to mock code. So I think what I can do is to inject my mock code in a separate js file into the page. The mock code in `mock.js` looks like as below:

```
ProductionFunc.prototype.load = function()
{  // return  fake data object}

ProductionFunc.prototype.save = function()
{  // fake save }
```

As a result, the `BODY` of `index.htm` in the browser should contain one line like `<script src="mock.js"></script>`

So the problem is how can I inject my mock code into the page without modifying the physical disk file `index.htm`.

There are about 100 test cases so 100 different mock js files are created respectively. I also created a `loader.htm` with 100 buttons on it. When a button is clicked, a new `index.htm` (injected with one mock js) opens. I wonder if the file name can be parameterized or not.

I know it can be done by some server side technology, such as ASP.NET. But I wonder if it can be done with pure Javascript without having to start a server process.

Comment: Why don't you just use a templating  engine like pug, ejs etc. ?

Comment: @h-sifat Hi, I'm a tester and I'm not allowed to change the target `index.htm`. To test the page, I need to change some production code to mock code. so I think what I can do is to inject my mock code in a seprate js file into the page. The mock code looks like `MyFunc.prototype.save= doFakeSave`. I'm not sure I'm clear of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Then why don't you just copy the file and manipulate it with node `fs` module. Read the file use a `regex` pattern may be to find where you want to inject code add the code and again write it to file. Simple I guess?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/ can help? See [`page.evaluateOnNewDocument()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluateonnewdocumentpagefunction-args).